# Create site template from site which had publishing enabled

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, site-template, publishing-page, publishing

I have an issue regarding publishing site. Basically I've had a publishing website created as a template, with multiple pages in pages list, each page has different webparts.

Then I disabled publishing to save the template.

The template is saved, but then when create a site using this site template, the publishing pages are there but they are empty (webparts are missing) and I cannot reactivate the publishing feature back ...

So is there a way to solve this?

Any idea how can i save a site as template which had a publishing enabled, espacially propagating those pages with the webparts and reactiating the publishing feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Publishing feature **does not support** the **Save Site as Template** option. It is necessary to create site definition templates for site collections on which Publishing feature is to be activated.
[SharePoint Publishing feature does not support "Save Site as Template" option](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2492356?wa=wsignin1.0)

So, In other words their are tons of issue even if you create a site template from publishing site.

You can try the below blog, he mentioned couple of method to save as template for publishing site. http://spdrummerboy.blogspot.com/2012/01/3-ways-to-save-sharepoint-2010.html

I think backup/restore or import/export is the best option.